# how to authenticate facebook user from facebook tab?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication, facebook-authorization

What is the wrong on my code when use **Facebook** tab to contain **game** . I  test it out the **facebook** and it worked well and authenticated facebook
user and when i returned on facebook tab it wrked well. is the problem
with redirection or what ? . i hope if any one help i searched more
but nothing .

**Facebook_login page**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string host = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["host"];
        string facebookClientId =
          System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookClientId"];
        string RedirectURL = "http://facebookapp.x.com";
        if (Request.QueryString["redirectURL"] != null)
        {
            RedirectURL = Request.QueryString["redirectURL"].ToString();
            Session["RedirectURL"] = RedirectURL;
        }
        Response.Redirect(@"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=" +
          facebookClientId + "&redirect_uri=http://" + host +
          @"/FBcallback.aspx&scope=publish_stream,offline_access,publish_actions");
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: I hadnot any error only when click on Facebook tab i have blank page .